# Finding the first instance of a product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table which contains a `Product Code` and a `Date Ordered` column. I need to find a way to find the first instance of each `Product Code` when they were ordered. I've tried just ordering and grouping the data, but it's not giving me what I need.

The table looks basically like this.

```
Product Code   Date Ordered
---------------------------
    A          2021-05-01
    A          2021-05-02
    B          2021-05-03
    B          2021-05-04
```

Comment: "I've tried just ordering and grouping the data, but it's not giving me what I need." - please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Also please show your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a `window function` ordered by your date and perhaps a `CTE`.

```
;with cte
as (
   select productcode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productcode ORDER BY dateOrdered) RN
   from tbl
   )
select *
from cte
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()` window function. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c27b342dec37da8dd834cc7ff0af452).

```
select
    productcode,
    dateOrdered 
from
(
    select 
        productcode,
        dateOrdered, 
        rank() over (partition BY productcode order by dateOrdered) as rn
    from yourTable
) q
where rn = 1
```